# CodeIgniter: Using group_by in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord

I have a db with "user_name" and "posts". How can I get a count of posts per username using CodeIgniter's db class?

In SQL:

```
SELECT 
  user_name, 
  COUNT(1) as post_count
FROM posts_by_user
GROUP BY user_name
```

In CodeIgniter:

```
$this->db->select('user_name', ???????);
$this->db->from('posts_by_user');
$this->db->group_by('user_name');
$result = $this->db->query();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$this->db->select('user_name, COUNT(*) as cnt', FALSE);
$this->db->from('posts_by_user');
$this->db->group_by('user_name');
$result = $this->db->get();

return $result->result();
```